# Should we bury the old tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

My tag crusade continues

The next tag I want to banish becaus I think it is a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) is [`old`](https://superuser.com/tags/old)

Is this a good idea?

Comment: It hits both blog definitions of a meta-tag rather well, so you have my support.

Comment: I agree it is useless, as knowing that a question is about something old is not that important to deserve a tag. Does the answer change if the tag is being used? Does the question get an answer quicker because the experts in old things follow that tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say yes. At first glance, I have no clue what a question tagged as `[old]` means, and as such  it's a useless tag to have.

Comment: Hopefully a mod will come along and fix this.

Comment: @Nifle you could post another question for that,